# Importing and inlining SVG in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, single-page-application

This is an SVG Circle:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 104 104">
  <circle cx="52" cy="52" r="50" stroke="#003EFF" stroke-width="4" fill="#00FF98" />
</svg>
```

This [Angular Project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-svg-circle?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) imports it like this:

```
import circle from './circle.svg';
```

And adds it to a `div` element like this:

```
<div [innerHTML]="svg" style="width:400px"><div>
```

But it looks like Angular XSS protection is stripping the content.  Is there a way to override this?

I tried the `DomSanitizer` like this:

```
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.trustedCircle = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.svg);
```

But no love.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Angular Material, comes in handy with this:

```
import { MatIconRegistry } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

In the constructor:

```
constructor(
    private matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,
    private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer
) { }
```

Add the icon or image in `ngInit`:

```
    this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
        'some-icon',
        this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
            '../img/some-icon.svg'
        )
    );
```

And then in your HTML:

```
        <mat-icon
            svgIcon="some-icon"
            class="icon-class"
            aria-label="some-icon">
        </mat-icon>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just fix it for you. You can try to see if it work

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer
} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import circle from './circle.svg';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  trustedCircle;
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.trustedCircle = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(circle);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ahhh - Shoot I had Url instead of Html ... Thank you.  I think it works now!