# Adding a custom icon to the matIconRegistry?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, svg, angular-material

I'm attempting to use the approach [in the answer to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57642008/importing-and-inlining-svg-in-angular) to implement a custom material icon [as shown in this Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-svg-demo?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

However it renders the error:

```
Error retrieving icon: Unable to find icon with the name ":circle-icon"
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official [Angular Material Example for loading custom SVG icons](https://material.angular.io/components/icon/examples) does not work on their [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/angular/xkndqeqameb?file=app%2Ficon-svg-example.ts) as of August 31, 2019.

This appears to be a Stackblitz issue that is unrelated to `matIconRegistry`.

See StackBlitz issue #72: [**Support images & static assets**](https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/72)